# Login in Android to an Api System

Tags: php, android, facebook, symfony, twitter

I'm trying to create an authentified API system using Symfony2.

So far, I created several Entities (Database tables) and I am able to authenticate an user by using nickname and a password.

Symfony2 Auth System, returns a cookie with a typical PHPSESSID. With this cookie, I can check which user is logged and give information related with that user.

However, I've the following problems:

- I don't know how can I login using POST sending user and password as params to Symfony Auth System.
- I don't really know if I can store a cookie (even retrieve it) in Android ( **NOTE** I'm using AndroidAnnotations. https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki )
- The last time I did an authentified API, I had to send user and password for every request. **Maybe this is kinda OK? If it's, I'd love keep using this system. Otherwise I look for a new one.**

**Notes**

- I'm in an openmind situation ATM. I'd like to use Twitter / FB authentication in a near future. Maybe using those systems leads to a simplier login system.

Feel free to give any tips / implementations!

Thanks.